# Retrieve an email address on the website

Tags: php

I am a publisher for Android application.

My website needs to retrieve Android application data automatically, but Google Play doesn't support API system like iTunes Store. Therefore, I need to make a PHP command that helps to retrieve Android Data. I need to get Title, App Image, description, and email addresses.

First, I was trying to get email address when I know Google Play URL address. Here is the example that I made. This is for Wall Street Journal app.

Wall Street Journal Android App URL - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wsj.reader_sp

```
<a href="mailto:mobilereader@wsj.com" rel="nofollow">Email Developer</a>
```

When I click the website and I can find the HTML codes like above.

```
$Google_Play_URL = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wsj.reader_sp';
$string = file_get_contents($Google_Play_URL);

$parsing = new SimpleXmlElement($string); 
$attrs = (array)$parsing->attributes(); 
$mail = str_replace('mailto:','',$attrs['href']); 
if(filter_var($mail,FILTER_VALIATE_MAIL))
{
   echo $mail;
}
```

The result should be "mobilereader@wsj.com", but it failed. Can you see the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Try to `print_r` or `var_dump` on variables (e.g. `$attrs`) and see if you got what you expect.

Comment: "FILTER_VALIATE_MAIL" should be "FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL"

Comment: that url returns an html page, which you're stuffing into simplexml. that means you're trying to retrieve the attributes of the xml root node, which is **NOT** going to contain an email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using PHP [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) like:

```
$Google_Play_URL = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wsj.reader_sp';
$string = file_get_contents($Google_Play_URL);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    if ($anchor->nodeValue === 'Email Developer') {
        $email = str_replace('mailto:', '', $anchor->getAttribute('href'));

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo $email;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output for the url you provided would be: `mobilereader@wsj.com`

Comment: I'd check if HREF contains 'mailto:' instead of checking nodeValue as it will be less prone to break if Google changes the link text as Google loves changing their layouts. =o)

Comment: Steven Farley   This one works, but it makes an error. A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 34

Filename: admin/db_advertisers.php

Line Number: 117

Comment: @Jake This would only happen if the HTML has entities like `&nbsp;` and there is a missing `;` at the end. You could suppress the warning using the `@` by changing this `$dom->loadHTML($string);` to `@$dom->loadHTML($string);` and the warning will be suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to match email address. Also, you had a typo in the filter name.

Try this:

```
$Google_Play_URL = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wsj.reader_sp';
$string = file_get_contents($Google_Play_URL);

preg_match('/<a href="mailto\:(.*)" rel="nofollow">Email Developer<\/a>/s', $string, $matches);
if (count($matches) > 0 && filter_var($matches[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_MAIL))
{
   echo $matches[1];
}
```